# How I can do this using skip and take in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dataset which contains more than 50k rows. I decided to take average of the first fifty values, then second fifty values and so on (so that I will get half of the Dataset with average of 50 value groups).

Here is my code:

```
var Rate = (from dr in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        rate = dr.Field<double>(columnName)
                                    }.rate).ToList();
                            if (Rate.Count > 50)
                            {
                                var avg = Rate.CheckRateValue();
                            }
```

And here is the code for my extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> CheckRateValue(this IEnumerable<double> values)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    for (; i < values.Count(); )
    {
        yield return values.Skip(j * 2).Take(2).Average();
        i = i + 2;
        j++;
    }
}
```

**Problem :**
It works fine but it's slow. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using row_number() i solved it.

```
declare @Skip int = 20
declare @Take int = 10

select SomeColumn
from (
   select SomeColumn,
          row_number() over(order by SomeColumnToOrderBy) as rn
   from YourTable
 ) T
where rn > @Skip and 
  rn <= @Skip + @Take
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) may be faster because you skip the iteration to create `List<dobule>`.

```
double average = (double)ds.Tables[0].Compute("avg(columnName)", "");
```

The second parameter is a fitler expression so you could use it to do your skipping if the data in the table allows it.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know you could do that. nifty.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourList=yourList.Take(50).Aggregate((acc, cur) => acc + cur) / list.Count
```

Comment: this is will not tak 50 per time, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take items in count of fifty and average it (like take first 50 , average it, take next 50, average it, and so on), and get list of Averages, you can use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).[Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs)

You can use

```
  var result = list.Batch(50).Select(x=> x.Average());
```

Comment: What is Batch() & your Link is taking us to MSDN LINQ Average() Page?

Answer (score 0):

Why would that be any faster than simply:

```
var average = dat.AsEnumerable().Average(dr => (double)dr["ColumnName"]);
```

In fact - this should probably be faster than the extra complexity of taking 50 at a time...

Answer (score 0):

for
{
  yield return values.Skip(j * 2).Take(2).Average();
}

Moving to the current page from the start in each loop iteration:  that will be n^2.  See also [Schlemiel the painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

You should enumerate `values` once!